# Composition of diffeomorphisms in the ADM formalism?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, diffeomorphism-invariance, adm-formalism

In the ADM formalism there are 4 constraints: $C_\mu(x)$, which are known as the Hamiltonian and spatial diffeomorphism constraints. In the quantum theory, $C_\mu(x)$ are the generators of diffeomorphisms. Since the product of two diffeomorphisms is another diffeomorphism I expect to be able to write
$$
\exp\left(\int dx ~f_1^\mu(x)C_{\mu}(x)\right)\exp\left(\int dx ~f_2^\mu(x)C_{\mu}(x)\right)\stackrel{?}{=}\exp\left(\int dx ~f_3^\mu(x)C_{\mu}(x)\right) \tag{1}
$$
where $f_{1,2}^\mu(x)$ are some fixed functions.

One can hope to evaluate the LHS using the BCH formula - in terms of nested commutators between the constraints. However, the constraints satisfy an *open* Lie algebra, i.e. the structure constants are functions of the 3-metric:
$$
[C_\mu,C_\nu]=f_{\mu\nu}^\alpha(h)C_{\alpha}
$$
Therefore, the nested commutators in the BCH formula will give us an exponent which in general cannot be put in the form $\int f_3^\mu C_\mu$. Therefore it appears that the product of diffeomorphisms is not a diffeomorphism, at least in the ADM picture.

Comment: You should be able to derive this from the constraint algebra.

Comment: Echoing @Prahar: Consider first infinitesimal diffeomorphisms.

Comment: @Prahar Hi Prahar. The trouble is that that the Lie algebra is open, meaning that nested commutators (as they arise in the BCH formula) will generally not yield back the constraints, meaning the RHS of (1) is doubtful for any $f_3$.